# Phonegap media plugin one sound at time

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I tried to make an image/sound gallery with PhoneGap media plugin, but I ran into one problem. When I click on a picture, the sound plays, but when I click on another one it plays that one too. Any idea how I can let them play one sound at a time?

```js
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Audio player
        //
        var my_media = null;
        var mediaTimer = null;

        // Play audio
        //
        function playAudio(src) {
            // Create Media object from src
            my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

            // Play audio
            my_media.play();

            // Update my_media position every second
            if (mediaTimer == null) {
                mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                    // get my_media position
                    my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                        // success callback
                        function(position) {
                            if (position > -1) {
                                setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                            }
                        },
                        // error callback
                        function(e) {
                            console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                            setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                        }
                    );
                }, 1000);
            }
        }

        // Pause audio
        //
        function pauseAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.pause();
            }
        }

        // Stop audio
        //
        function stopAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.stop();
            }
            clearInterval(mediaTimer);
            mediaTimer = null;
        }

        // onSuccess Callback
        //
        function onSuccess() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        }

        // onError Callback
        //
        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

        // Set audio position
        //
        function setAudioPosition(position) {
            document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
        }

        </script>
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="playAudio('http://design.ps4fix.co.uk/arMonika/Audio.mp3');"><img src="arMonika/audio.png" width="147" height="147" /></a>
<a href="#"class="btnlarge"onclick="playAudio('http://design.ps4fix.co.uk/arMonika/komp.v.sepc.mp3');"><img src="arMonika/k.tech.spec.png" width="141" height="141" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who have the same issue :
When you start defining your player , player or "Media" stores in variable , in your case it is "my_media" .

To solve this problem just define your variable "my_media" as a global var. 
and then for each link that should play sound you need to stop your previos media and store new media in that variable like this :

```
      my_media.stop
      new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
```

just becareful about defining its variable as a GLOBAL variable.

Hoped it helps.